# Ajax redirecting to system configuration page in admin custom module

Tags: magento-1.7, ajax

Hello I have made a custom admin module, in which I am uploading image using using Ajax and for this I am using ajaxfileupload library.

this is my edit.php file code which uses ajax code-

```
<?php
class Assel_Character_Block_Adminhtml_Character_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container {

    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();                      
        $this->_objectId = 'id';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'character';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_character';
        $this->_mode='edit';


        $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('character')->__('Save Character'));
        $this->_updateButton('delete', 'label', Mage::helper('character')->__('Delete Character'));


        $this->_addButton('saveandcontinue', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Save And Continue Edit'),
            'onclick'   => 'saveAndContinueEdit()',
            'class'     => 'save',
        ), -100);

        $pathToMethod=$this->getUrl('*/*/fileUpload'); /*url of method in controller file to process on file or image*/

        $this->_formScripts[] = "var pathToMethod="."'".$pathToMethod."'";/*assign url of controller method in js variable to use in ajax below*/
        $script  = 
<<<EOD

            function saveAndContinueEdit(){
                editForm.submit($('edit_form').action+'back/edit/');
            }

            jQuery(function($){
                var btnUpload=$('#upload');
                var status=$('#status');

                new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
                    action:'pathToMethod', /*call the method in controller file in custom module*/
                    name: 'uploadfile',
                    onSubmit: function(file, ext){
                         if (! (ext && /^(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$/.test(ext))){ 

                            status.text('Only JPG, PNG or GIF files are allowed');
                            return false;
                        }
                        status.text('Uploading...');
                    },
                    onComplete: function(file, response){

                        status.text('');

                        if(response==="success"){
                            $('<li></li>').appendTo('#files').html('<img src="./uploads/'+file+'" alt="" /><br />'+file).addClass('success');
                        } else{
                            $('<li></li>').appendTo('#files').text(response).addClass('error');
                        }
                    }
                });

            });
EOD;

        $this->_formScripts[] = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "", $script );

    }
```

My problem is this Ajax call is giving the HTML of whole page of **System->configuration** in admin in response instead of calling method defined in controller.

What is wrong there in my code, somebody there to help me.?

Answer (score 1):

There could be several things wrong here but your action for the Ajax would be a good place to start:

```
action:'pathToMethod' should be: action:pathToMethod
```

pathToMethod is a variable and should be used as one and not as a string.

Comment: hello paras, I have made edit which you told me but not worked even I have hardcored the url of controller action in  js script like action:"http://localhost/bulksms/index.php/character/adminhtml_ajax/fileUpload", and also tried with key url like action:"http://localhost/bulksms/index.php/character/adminhtml_ajax/fileUpload/key/8bb0eea374d9345a2afc40a3e09d3d89/"  but also in this case same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Since the pathToMethod variable is created in PHP and you want to use it in the script you should probably echo or concatenate it to your script.