# How to Call controller method using Ajax from a block file in Magento custom module

Tags: magento-1.7, custom-options, ajax

I want to call a method defined in controller using AJAX from my custom module's block folder .php file.

how I can do that.?

Comment: Can you tell is exactly what you want to achieve? You initiate an AJAX/XHR request from the front-end using Javascript, not in a .php file. If you tell us something more about your end game we can probably help you better.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Marco , please refer this URL "http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/46549/ajax-redirecting-to-system-configuration-page-in-admin-custom-module"

Answer (score 2):

Magento uses PrototypeJS for Ajax, please refer to the documentation:

http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/Updater/ if you want to display the response as HTML inside an existing element.

http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/Request/ for any other kind of Ajax request

You get the URL to your controller as usual with `$this->getUrl('module/controller/action')`