# file upload is not working in magento

Tags: adminhtml, upload

This is my phtml file:

```
<form method="GET" action="<?php echo Mage::helper("adminhtml")
->getUrl('management/adminhtml_task/show')?>" name="commentForm" id="commentForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Comments:</td>

<td><textarea name="comments1" id="comments1" rows="2" cols="70"></textarea></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>File Upload:</td>
<td><input type="file" name="files" id="files" ></td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="submit" id="button23">Submit1</button></td>

</tr>


</table>
</form>
```

this is my action:

```
if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getParams()) {

    if ((!empty($_FILES["files"]["name"])))
        {
        print_r($_FILES);exit;
        $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('files');
        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
        $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media');
        $fileName = $_FILES['files']['name'];
        $uploader->save($path, $fileName);
        }}
```

n my o/p is

Array()

I can't get file in $_FILES how to solve this problem

Comment: Your form method should be `post` not `GET`.

Comment: when i use post method n click on button it redirect to Dashboard/Magento Admin i can't understand why this happens please help me

Comment: Ok. I know you problem. I will post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your form should have the method `post` not `GET`. You cannot send files through GET.
Second...there is a security measure for the magento admin.  All `POST` requests must contain a form key that depends on the session. This way [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) attacks are prevented.
So you need to include a hidden input in your form with the name `form_key` and the value your current session form key.
Add this inside your form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()?>" />
```

Comment: if in form action="#" n using ajax in  ajaxcode url: '<?php echo Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl('management/adminhtml_task/view')?>' n in action print_r($_FILES); again o/p is Array()

Comment: in ajax file upload work or not?

Comment: You cannot upload files through AJAX. You have to use a trick. See this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/46429/146